# Using if and shell variables inside an awk script

Tags: awk, data

I am trying to get data from a file that is like this:

```
  6   6   1   0
  0.1166667E+02  0.4826611E-09  0.4826611E-09  0.3004786E-09  0.5000000E-15
  1.000000000000000E-004
  CAR 
 system-001                       
     10.51965443    -34.96542345  301      1.95329810      1.00000000
-15.558  0.1631E+01  0.1597E+02
-15.407  0.1661E+02  0.1779E+02
-15.255  0.4253E+01  0.1990E+02
-15.104  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
-14.952  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.884  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.732  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.581  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.429  0.0000E+00  0.2000E+02
 -3.277  0.8214E-03  0.2000E+02
 -3.126  0.3543E+00  0.2002E+02
  1.726  0.1019E+01  0.4386E+02
  1.877  0.5581E+00  0.4399E+02
  2.029  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.181  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.332  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.484  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.636  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.787  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  2.939  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.090  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.242  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.394  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.545  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.697  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  3.849  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  4.000  0.0000E+00  0.4400E+02
  4.152  0.6271E-01  0.4400E+02
  4.303  0.4520E+01  0.4433E+02
  4.455  0.5040E+01  0.4511E+02
```

I want to take always the fourth column from the 6 line (1.95329810 in this case), then look for its closest value in the following lines, from the first column(1.877 in this case). That only for referencing, after founding that, I want to extract the next line which its second column is non zero (4.152).

So I would like to get 1.95329810 and 4.152 as output, so I can substract them and get:

```
band_gap=4.152-$fermi_energy
```

By taking in consideration @DopeGhoti s answer, I used his code with an if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
fermi_energy=$(awk 'NR==6 {printf $4}' DOSCAR-62.4902421.st)
awk -f go.awk DOSCAR-62.4902421.st
```

Where the `go.awk` file is:

```
BEGIN { 
test=0
}
NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
   keptvalue=$1
}
NF == 3 && test == 0 && $2 == "0.0000E+00" {
   #print keptvalue
   test=1
}
NF == 3 && test == 1 && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
   if ( sqrt(($fermi_energy-$1)**2) < 0.5 ) 
   {
       print $1
       test=0
   }
}
```

But I think that it is not the right way to use bash variables inside an awk script.

P.D. **In the case you are wondering**, the data represents the calculations of the [Density Of States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states) of the electrons of an oxide. The first column represents the electron's energies, the second the electron's amount in that energy level. Therefore, when looking for the next non '0.0000E+00' value since the closest level of the [Fermi Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_level), we can calculate the energy required to make the electrons jump and conduct electricity. (Metals have zero band gap, thus they do not need energy input to conduct electricity)

Comment: How do you define "nearest"? isn't 2.029 nearer than 1.877 to 1.95329810, in absolute terms?

Comment: @steeldriver you are right, but as you may have read, I do not need to consider that value, because it has '0.0000E+00' in its second column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer below makes a number of changes to your technique.

1. Do it all in a single `awk` program instead of two. You can do that because your second run only deals with lines after line 6:
2. Properly assign your fermi_energy value from line 6.
3. No longer need to check for `NF==3` because *all* lines after line 6 fulfill that criteria.
4. Eliminate variable `test`, and instead let's keep a running tab of the minimum difference between `fermi_energy` and `$1`. For that, we will create a variable `min` which will initially have a ridiculously large value, guaranteed to fail the first test. We'll also assign understandable names to the other variables, and print only one result, after testing all lines of the file.
5. Replace your computationally heavy absolute value test with a computationally light zero test.
6. Note that `awk` supports floating point scientific notation. For example, in a `printf` command, one may use the format `%E`. As usual, see the `man` page or your favorite search engine for more.
7. All this done with no understanding of particle physics, so I may have got something incorrect. Pardon. If so, I hope at least this puts you on the right track.

   ```
   awk '
       BEGIN  { min=1000 ; jump_energy="INIT" }
       function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
       NR==6 {fermi_energy=$4}
       NR>6 {
           if (jump_energy != 0) {
               this_diff=abs(fermi_energy-$1)
               if (this_diff < min) {
                   min=this_diff
                   energy_level=0
                   jump_energy=0
                   getline
               }
           }
           if (jump_energy == 0  && $2 != "0.0000E+00") {
               energy_level=$1
               jump_energy=$2
           }
       }
       END {
           printf "  Fermi Energy: %f\n  Energy Level: %f\n  Jump Energy: %E\n", fermi_energy, energy_level, jump_energy
       }'
   ```

Comment: That is very cool! But I think there are some errors in the code, as number of { openings is not equal to the } closings. Could you help me, please?

Comment: I think I messed up your code formatting. I pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/MXvhzhfZ . As you may see by running the code it gives some syntax errors. 
`awk: second.awk:6:       jump_energy != 0 {
awk: second.awk:6:                        ^ syntax error
awk: second.awk:8:         this_diff < min {
awk: second.awk:8:                         ^ syntax error
awk: second.awk:15:       jump_energy == 0  && $2 != "0.0000E+00" {
awk: second.awk:15:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: second.awk:19:     END {
awk: second.awk:19:     ^ syntax error`

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar - yes! So sorry. I had the `if` statement syntax wrong; I thought I could nest address ranges, like I remember in `sed`.

Comment: Would you like to recommend me a good book or tutorial for learning awk? I was using this one from TutorialsPoint, but it does not look very complete https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_tutorial.pdf

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar - I would like to, but I don't know enough about what literature is out there and current to be the best person to make a recommendation. Also, the code has been updated.

Comment: I got another error message. Maybe we have to separate the values with commas right? I did it and still getting the error. Or does the END statement makes any difference to put it at the EOF? `awk: second.awk:21: (FILENAME=TESTCAR FNR=36) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
          Fermi Energy: %s
  Energy Level: %s
  Jump Energy: %s10.51965443-34.96542345'
                         ^ ran out for this one`

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar - yes, corrected in cross-talk already. See update. My other error was using the incorrect format specifiers `%s` is for string, and we want float and scientific notation. My bad, I should have originally tested with the actual data instead of just coding the answer. Note how `awk` adjusts the scientific notation of the jump energy so that the first digit is never zero.

Comment: Now I get it. I am learning a lot of you. The output I get is: `Fermi Energy: 0.000000
  Energy Level: 10.519654
  Jump Energy: -3.496542E+01
` But actually, I was expecting to get 2,1987019, the result of 4.152 minus (the fourth column, sixth line) 1.95329810. That is subtracting the first number in the first column that has a non zero value(4.152) that follows from the closest  value to 1.95329810 (in this case 1.877)

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar - Hmm, my results are:   Fermi Energy: 1.953298  Energy Level: 4.152000  Jump Energy: 6.271000E-02

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar : I think I see a difference. My version has ` NR>6 {` with the brace on the same line, not on a dedicated separate line. Try that, please.

Comment: I owe you one. I learned a lot!

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar - You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR == 6 { fe = $4 }
     NR > 6 && $1 > fe && $2 > 0 { print fe, $1; exit }' file
```

For the given input data in `file` this will produce

```
1.95329810 4.152
```

The `awk` script ignores the first five lines of input. At line six, it picks out the fourth field an assigns it to the variable `fe` (short ofr "Fermi energy".

The code then assumes that the values in column one are increasing, and when the first of these first column values reaches a value above the value stored in `fe`, and if the second column is non-zero, it prints out `fe` and the value from the first column and exits.

Unfortunately, I don't *fully* understand your longer code segment as there is no explanation of what you actually want it to do.